# Is a websocket connection handled by one single lambda instance on AWS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, websocket

If I have a websocket connection:

```
client <=> AWS Lambda [Python]
```

While a connection is active: Will the client be connected to the same lambda instance for the whole time or can it change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a (persistent) WebSocket connection to a (transient) Lambda function. Instead you have a WebSocket connection to something persistent that proxies requests to Lambda functions, and that proxy is typically [API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-overview.html).

No, the client won't be connected, even indirectly, to the same instance of a Lambda function for the entirety of the WebSocket connection. Lambda is stateless so WebSocket applications using Lambda typically store state e.g. client connection IDs in DynamoDB.

There's a WebSocket-based example in the [announcement blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-websocket-apis-in-amazon-api-gateway/) that's helpful to understand how connection IDs are handled and how the back-end sends messages to all connected clients.